# How to compare an address with an address using web3js?

Tags: web3js, javascript

I've been reading and trying but to no avail. I'm trying to compare the current wallet address in MetaMask with the wallet address which owns a certain token via a smart contract method "ownerOf" which returns the address of the token owner.

I tried using "valueOf()", "JSON.stringify()", toString() and also "localcompare" and none worked. Localcompare always return a value of more than 0 even the two addresses match.

Below is my code.

```
async function doesTokenIdExist(tokenId, contract, walletAddress) {


  await contract.methods.ownerOf(tokenId).call(function(err,res){
        if(!err){

            console.log("Output of localeCompare: " + res.localeCompare(walletAddress));

            if (tokenAddress.localeCompare(walletAddress) == 0){
                console.log("Wallet owner owns tokenId");
                setTokenExist();
            } 

        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should use toLowerCase() on both addresses, and better to console.log them first and see if one of them has "0x" or if they already equal

Comment: Gosh! You're a genius. I actually been outputting every single output I could and didn't realize the case. Yeah, some addresses have all small caps while some mix of big and small caps. Never thought blockchain coding is soo tricky.

Comment: you are welcome, it happen to me alot ;-)